# Python Pandas : Append does not return the required values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append

I have two dataframes, when I use append concept the same does not return the required result.

```
firstDF = pd.DataFrame({'mac':[1,3],'location':[['kitchen', 'kitchen', 'kitchen', 'kitchen', 'kitchen'],['conference']]})
predictedDF = pd.DataFrame({'mac':[2],'location':[['lab']]})

if predictedDF['mac'].isin(firstDF['mac']).any():
    pass
else:

    firstDF.append(predictedDF,ignore_index=True)
```

The same returns the result as,

```
      mac                                       location
 0    1    [kitchen, kitchen, kitchen, kitchen, kitchen]
 1    3                                     [conference]
```

whereas I should get the result as,

```
 mac                                       location
 0    1    [kitchen, kitchen, kitchen, kitchen, kitchen]
 1    3                                     [conference]
 2    2                                            [lab]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign back, because use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), not `python append`:

```
if predictedDF['mac'].isin(firstDF['mac']).any():
    pass
else:

    firstDF = firstDF.append(predictedDF,ignore_index=True)

print (firstDF)
   mac                                       location
0    1  [kitchen, kitchen, kitchen, kitchen, kitchen]
1    3                                   [conference]
2    2                                          [lab]
```